# Bash variable manipulation

Tags: bash, variables

I am very new to Bash Scripting and can not find any help online for the more basic stuff. My task is to run a program that attempts to take a user input and get it to 1 by dividing even numbers by 2 and multiplying odd numbers by 3 and adding 1. I don't know any advanced commands and I'm sure there are easier ways to do this but I cant quite understand why my code is giving me the "Command Not found" error from gedit.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Takes in a number and computes it into hailstone series while
#displaying each number onto the screen
echo Enter number:
read n

while [$n -gt 1] 
do
 if [$n % 2 -eq 0]
  then 
   let n=n/2
   echo $n
 else
  let n=n*3+1
  echo $n the number is header
 fi
done
```

My variable keeps skipping the first if statement and returning my "is header" check statement and I don't want it to. If I input 8 it should be modded by 2 -eq 0, therefore it should divide until it equals 1 or less.

Comment: You're not being careful enough with the spacing.  You must use `[ $n -gt 1 ]` because the command name is `[` and the last argument to `[` must be `]`.  Or you can use `[[` which is laxer about the spacing.  Shell scripting requires a lot of care about spaces.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend, for finding syntax bugs without needing to get humans involved.

Comment: btw, in terms of how to think about it: `[` is a **command**, not language syntax. Just as you need to use two words to run `ls mydir` instead of `lsmydir`, you need to run `[ foo` instead of `[foo` to prevent the shell from looking for a different command named `[foo`. If you want things to be less confusing, use the command `test "$n" -gt 1` instead of `[ "$n" -gt 1 ]`, as `test` looks less like something that would be syntax elsewhere.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, spaces are still required after `[[` and before `]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put space after `[` and before `]`. So instead of `while [$n -gt 1]`, write `while [ $n -gt 1 ]`.

The same goes for `[$n % 2 -eq 0]`, but that won't be much help because there's no `%` operator in `[ ... ]`. You can use `((...))` instead.
I also rewrote the `let` commands with the simpler and more intuitive `((...))` syntax.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter number:
read -r n

while ((n > 1))
do
    if ((n % 2 == 0))
    then 
        ((n /= 2))
        echo $n
    else
        ((n = n * 3 + 1))
        echo $n the number is header
    fi
done
```

Comment: @Rep I further improved it a bit.

Comment: Bless your soul sir. Thanks for the help everyone 07